# How to pull the most recent values from a T-SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have a database table that I need to process with either a view or a stored procedure or something else that gives me a result based on the live data.

The table holds records of people with data associated with each one. The thing is that people can be in the table more than once. Each record shows a time when one or more pieces of information was recorded for an individual.

The identifier field for the people is cardholder_index. I need to take a DISTINCT list of that field. There is also a date field called bio_complete_date. What I need to do is, for all the other fields in the table, take the most recent non-null (or possibly non-zero) value.

For instance, there is a bmi field. For each distinct cardholder index, I need to take the most recent (by the bio_complete_date field) non-null bmi for that cardholder_index. But there's also a body_fat field, and I need to take the most recent non-null value in that field, which might not necessarily be the same row as the most recent non-null bmi value.

For the record, the table itself does have its own unique identifier column, bio_id, if that helps.

I don't need to show *when* the most recent piece of information was taken. I just need to show the data itself.

I figure I need to do a distinct on the card_holder index, and then join to it the result sets of querys for each other field. It's writing the subqueries that is giving me problems.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  Also, showing us some sample data as well as desired output would be helpful.

Comment: do you have an example, names of tables, fields, where clauses, etc.?

Comment: It's good that you explain it in words, but you need to provide sample data and sample output. Keep in mind, we don't have the data sitting in front of us. If you can't share the actual data, generate some dummy data that matches the actual table.

Comment: Or to be specific, what are the problems that you refer to in your last sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I guess your table looks something like this:

```
create table people (
    bio_id int identity(1,1), 
    cardholder_index int, 
    bio_complete_date date, 
    bmi int, 
    body_fat int
)
```

If so, one way (of many) to do the query would be to use correlated queries to pull the latest non-null value for the cardholder_index, either using subqueries like this:

```
select 
    cardholder_index, 
    (
       select top 1 bmi 
       from people 
       where cardholder_index = p.cardholder_index and bmi is not null 
       order by bio_complete_date desc
    ) as latest_bmi, 
    (
       select top 1 body_fat 
       from people 
       where cardholder_index = p.cardholder_index and body_fat is not null 
       order by bio_complete_date desc
    ) as latest_body_fat
from people p
group by cardholder_index
```

or to use the `apply` operator like this:

```
select cardholder_index, latest_bmi.bmi, latest_body_fat.body_fat
from people p
outer apply (
    select top 1 bmi 
    from people 
    where cardholder_index = p.cardholder_index and bmi is not null 
    order by bio_complete_date desc
) as latest_bmi
outer apply (
    select top 1 body_fat 
    from people 
    where cardholder_index = p.cardholder_index and body_fat is not null 
    order by bio_complete_date desc
) as latest_body_fat
group by cardholder_index, latest_bmi.bmi, latest_body_fat.body_fat
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20130/2)

Comment: I have never heard of the apply operator before but it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Both of your answers work. I'll go ahead and do the whole table both ways and see which runs faster.

Thanks!

Comment: @Hypersapien Apply can be pretty useful - this query might not be the best case for it though; the first query should be faster. Both should benefit from an index on people for `cardholder_index, bio_complete_date desc`

Comment: I tried turning this into a view, and it doesn't let me add indexes to views that have either subqueries or use APPLY.

Comment: @Hypersapien Oh. You should be able to add the index to the underlying table though, but if your data set isn't very large the presence of an index might not matter much anyway.

Comment: Oh! That's what you meant. It already had an index on bio_id. The query I wrote is still taking something like 20 seconds to run with either method. Boss decided to take the query and turn it into a sproc that we pass the cardholder_index into so we can just call the information on one person at a time, and it works great that way.

Comment: @Hypersapien Even if you have an index for bio_id the query would probably not benefit from it, adding another index as described above should though as what's going to cost is the cardholder_index and bio_complete_date comparisons. It sounds like you have a working solution anyway so that's great :)

Comment: I just checked again, and it had one on cardholder_index as well as a bunch of others (I was only looking at the primary key in design view before, not the actual indexes/keys dialog box)

Comment: For the record, the source table has 200000 rows, and the full query was trying to return 87000.